# Revisited$^2$: Why is $(-n)^2$ divergent? How can it be shown rigorously?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

Why is $(-n)^2$ divergent? How is this proven? I've tried using the $\epsilon$ definition of convergence to come to a contradiction, but I don't know that using the definition is the way to go. I get that $n^2-s\leq \frac{1}{n}$. Not sure where to go from here. A hint would be nice.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

### Attempt1:

Say $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}=(-n)^2=s$. Then given an $\epsilon>0$ we can find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\lvert (-n)^2-s\rvert \leq \epsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. But if $n\geq N$, then we must have that
$$\lvert (-n)^2-s\rvert\leq \frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N},$$
but . . . hmm . . . I don't know that this is a fruitful approach.

---

[image]

---

### Attempt2:

Assuming that the negation of convergence is

> $$\text{$\exists\epsilon\leq 0$ s.t. $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ $n>N$ so that $\lvert s_n-s\rvert \geq \epsilon$},$$

then if we let $\epsilon=0$, then $\lvert s_n-s\rvert \geq \epsilon\implies \lvert n^2-s\rvert \geq 0$, which means that $n^2\geq s$ and $s\geq n^2$, so $s=n^2$, which means $\lvert s_n-s\rvert \geq \epsilon$ holds as $0\geq 0$, right?

Comment: You mean the sequence $1,4,9,16,\dots$? Isn't it clear that $(-n)^2\ge n$ for all $n\ge1$?

Comment: Yes, @anon, but mathematics is about proving what one asserts.

Comment: What’s $s$? You need to prove that this sequence *diverges*, i.e. it violates the defintion of convergence, i.e. it satisfies the negation of the definition of convergence, i.e. you need to show that for any possible limit $a$ there is a distance $ε$ and there are infinitely many non-negative numbers $n$ such that $(-n)^2$ is farer away from the limit $a$ than $ε$, i.e. $∀a ∈ ℝ ∃ε>0 ∀N∈ℕ ∃n∈ℕ, n>N:\; |a-a_n| ≥ ε$, where $a_n = (-n)^2$.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Exactly how are you defining a sequence to be divergent? By it not being convergent? Do you have a definition of $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}a_n=+\infty$?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my question.

Comment: Can you prove that $1,2,3,4,\dots$ is divergent?

Comment: $s$ is the limit of the sequence.

Comment: Then **hint**: Read my previous comment and for any limit $s$ take $ε$ to be $1$. Visualize this. For any $N ∈ ℕ$, you then need to find $n ∈ ℕ, n > N$ such that $n^2 = (-n)^2$ is greater than $s$ by at least $1$. Visualize this.

Comment: The negation of $\forall \epsilon>0$ is not $\exists \epsilon\le 0$ but rather $\exists \epsilon>0$.

Comment: $|n^2 - s| \ge 0$ does **not** mean $n^2 \ge s$ and $s \ge n^2$. (Replace "and" with "or".) It just means that the absolute value of the difference is nonnegative — which by the way, is always true, as the absolute value function only takes nonnegative values by definition. Your expression for the negation of convergence is a very incorrect one.

Comment: To negate a condition, start outwards and do it one step at a time. Start with "for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that [P]". Its negation is that "for not every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that [P]", i.e. "there exists $\epsilon>0$ for which there does not exist $N$ such that [P]". Same as "there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $N$, [P] is false". Carrying this to the end, you can write down the negation of convergence to $s$ as "$\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n\ge N$ such that $|s_n-s|\ge \epsilon$". Now say this for all $s$.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, I do.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Have you read Peter's [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/487054/55235)?

Comment: According to your book's definition, the sequence $\left(\Bbb (-n)^2\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is convergent if, and only if,
$$(\exists s\in \Bbb R)(\forall \varepsilon >0)(\exists N\in \Bbb N)(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(n\ge N\implies |(-n^2)-s|<\varepsilon).$$

Suppose that $\left(\Bbb (-n)^2\right)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is convergent, then there exist $s$ such that
$$(\forall \varepsilon >0)(\exists N\in \Bbb N)(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(n\ge N\implies |n^2-s|<\varepsilon)$$
Particularizing for $\varepsilon=1$ one gets that there exists $N\in \Bbb N$ such that
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(n\ge N\implies |n^2-s|<1)$$

Comment: Particularizing for $N$ and $N+1$ yields
$$N\ge N\implies \left|N^2-s\right|<1\text{ and } N+1\ge N\implies \left|(N+1)^2-s\right|<1.$$
Therefore $\left|N^2-s\right|<1\text{ and } \left|(N+1)^2-s\right|<1$, which implies $$\begin{align}N^2&<s+1\\ N^2+2N+1&<s+1\end{align}.$$

Subtracting the first inequality from the second yields $\color{grey}{0<}2N+1<0$, which is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Claim** Every convergent sequence is bounded.

**Proof** Suppose that $x_n\to x$. Given $\epsilon =1$, there is $N$ such that if $n\geqslant N$ then $$|x_n|-|x|<|x-x_n|<1$$ so when $n\geqslant N$ $$|x_n|<1+|x|$$

Then for each $n$ we have $$|x_n|\leq \max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_{N-1}|,|x|+1\}$$

**Observation** The sequence $a_n=(-n)^2$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest to use the negation of the definition of Cauchy sequence:

There exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $N$, there is some $n,m > N$ such that $|x_n - x_m| > \epsilon$.

Take time to parse this statement and it won't be too bad to prove what you want.

Comment: Should add K. Stm.'s comments are the way to go if you haven't seen Cauchy sequences yet.

Comment: So you are saying that $\exists\epsilon\leq 0$ s.t. $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $\lvert s_m-s_n\rvert \geq \epsilon$ with $n\geq N$ and $m\geq N$?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte  yes, but for /some/ $n,m$ (not for all $n,m > N$.

Comment: @Loie: The definitions I usually use take strict inequalities. Normally I wouldn't care but since you seem particularly interested in a completely airtight proof, make sure you are using $\geq$ when the definition says $\geq$, or $>$ when the definition says $>$.

Comment: @EricStucky What are you saying?

Answer (score 1):

Working from the definition ,$\forall L \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists \epsilon > 0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \exists \ n > N : |n^2 - L| \geq \epsilon$.

If L is negative or zero, it is easy to see that $n^2 + L$ that $\forall n \geq 1 \ n^2 + L > L.$  Choose $\epsilon = |L|, $ so $|n^2 - L| = n^2 + L > |L| = \epsilon.$

If L is positive, and $N \leq \lfloor\sqrt{L}\rfloor$ and N $\neq \sqrt{L}$, choose $\epsilon = L$. Then:

$\forall n \geq \lceil{\sqrt{2L}}\rceil, \ |\lceil{\sqrt{2L}}\rceil^2 - L| \geq |\sqrt{2L}^2 - L| = |L| = L = \epsilon.$

If L is positive and $N = \sqrt{L}$ or $N \geq \lceil\sqrt{L}\rceil$, then $\forall n \geq N \ |(n+1)^2 - L| > |n^2 -L|.$

Choose $\epsilon = |(N+1)^2 -L|$ so $\forall n \geq N + 2$:

$|n^2 - L| > |(N+1)^2 -L| = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $N > 0$, we can choose any number $N'$ such that
$\quad n > N'\ \Longrightarrow\ -n^{2} < N$.

For a given $N \leq 0\quad$,
$\forall\ n > \left\lfloor\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}-N\,} + 1\right\rfloor$
it's true that $-n^{2} < N$.

Answer (score -1):

Note that $(-n)^2 = (-1)^2 n^2= n^2$. So, proving that $(-n)^2 \to \infty$ is the same as proving that $n^2 \to \infty$, which is an easy and well known proof.

Comment: Yes, how clever are you, but I don't know that you are too aware of what a proof is.

Comment: To prove that $n^2 \to \infty$, just take $K>0 \in \Bbb R$, we can choose a natural number $N > \sqrt{R}$ and then $N^2 > R$, so for any real number there is an element of the sequence that is larger, it means that the sequence tends to $\infty$. P.S. You should be nicer to the people who tries to help you.

Comment: I'm not saying this isn't a proof, but in the context the OP provided it is as much a proof as it is this one: $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}(-n)^2=+\infty _\blacksquare$. The comment above, however, might make for a good answer.